# Put array items in a list and print out the list items in C

Tags: c, pointers

In this program, I want to put the element in the list rather than an array. And lastly print out the list.

eg. 
simon    22
suzie    24
...

However, I dont really understand how to manipulate the list, and how I can build the heap and retrieve it. I did some research about how to do it. And this is what I come up. 
And some of the error comes out and I have no idea how to fix.

```
error: 'ptr' undeclared (first use in this function)
arrays.c:37:5: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function     it appears in
arrays.c: In function 'main':
arrays.c:62:9: error: expected identifier or '(' before '=' token
arrays.c:69:5: warning: passing argument 1 of 'insert' from incompatible pointer type
arrays.c:28:13: note: expected 'struct Record *' but argument is of type 'struct Record **'

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


/* these arrays are just used to give the parameters to 'insert',
   to create the 'people' array */
char *names[7]= {"Simon", "Suzie", "Alfred", "Chip", "John", "Tim",
          "Harriet"};
int ages[7]= {22, 24, 106, 6, 18, 32, 24};


/* declare your struct for a person here */
/* */
typedef struct Record{
    char *names;
    int ages;
    struct Record *next;
}  Record;

char getname(Record *names){
    return names;
}

int getage(Record *ages){
    return ages;  
}

static void insert (Record *p, char *s, int n) {

//p[(*)] = malloc(sizeof(person));

/*static int nextfreeplace = 0;*/
    Record *headptr = NULL;

    while(!reached_eof(p)){

/* allocate heap space for a record */
        ptr =(Record*) malloc(sizeof(Record));

        if(ptr == NULL){  
            abort();
            printf("memory allocation fail"); 
            exit(1);  
        }
        else{
            printf("memory allocation to person  - %s - \n", s);      
        }

        ptr->name = getname(p);
        ptr->age = getage(p);

        /* link new object into the list */
        ptr->next = headptr;
        headptr = ptr;

    }
}       


int main( int argc, char **argv) {

    /* declare nextinsert */
    int  = 0;            

    /* declare the people array here */
    Record *p, *headptr;
    headptr = NULL;

    //insert the members and age into the unusage array. 
    for ( int i=0 ; i < 7; i++) {
        insert (p, names[i], ages[i]);

        /* do not dereference the pointer */
    }

    /* print out a line before printing the names and ages */
     printf("\n");


    /* print the people array here*/
    for (int i=0; i < 7; i++) {
        printf("The name is: %s, the age is:%i\n", p[i]->names, p[i]->ages);
    }


    /* This is the third loop for call free to release the memory allocated by malloc */
    /* the free()function deallocate the space pointed by ptr. */
    for(int i=0; i<7;i++){
        free(p[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all

The following code is wierd

```
char getname(Record *names){
  return names;
}

int getage(Record *ages){
  return ages;  
}
```

I do not see any real need for the above function.

even these lines

```
ptr->name=getname(p);
ptr->age=getage(p);
```

you can relace them with

```
ptr->name=s;
ptr->age=n;
```

The following function contains many errors and strange codes:

```
static void insert (Record *p, char *s, int n) {

//p[(*)] = malloc(sizeof(person));

/*static int nextfreeplace = 0;*/
   Record *headptr = NULL;

   while(!reached_eof(p)){
/* allocate heap space for a record */
ptr =(Record*) malloc(sizeof(Record));

if(ptr == NULL){  
   abort();
   printf("memory allocation fail"); 
   exit(1);  
}else{
   printf("memory allocation to person  - %s - \n", s);      
}
```

Why you are using while loop. and you missed the definition of ptr pointer and you have note communicate the neaw header at the end of the function. here after how you can fix it:

```
static void insert (Record **header, char *s, int n) {

   Record *ptr;
   ptr =(Record*) malloc(sizeof(Record));

    if(ptr == NULL){  
       abort();
       printf("memory allocation fail"); 
       exit(1);  
    }else{
       printf("memory allocation to person  - %s - \n", s);      
    }
    ptr->name=s;
    ptr->age=n;

    /* link new object into the list */
    ptr->next=*header;
    *headptr=ptr;
}
```

**And in your main function:**

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {


   int  i= 0;
  Record *p, *headptr=NULL;

for (int i=0; i < 7; i++) {
insert (&headptr, names[i], ages[i]);
/* do not dereference the pointer */
  }

 for (int i=0; i < 7; i++) { /* this will print from array*/
    printf("From array  The name is: %s, the age is:%i\n", p[i]->names, p[i]->ages);
}

for (p=headptr; p!=NULL; p=p->next) {  /* this will print from linked list*/
    printf("From linked list The name is: %s, the age is:%i\n", p->names, p->ages);
}


}
```

Comment: the fixed code will inserrt your element in the head of the list

Answer (score 0):

I guess the only error is you missed defining pointer before you use it with malloc function. Defining pointer as

```
Record *ptr ;
```

And somewhere in you code has the following text:

```
int = 0;
```

that's the second error.

And you are passing a NULL pointer `p` to insert function on your for loop

Edit these, and they must fix errors now.